# Facebook Graph API and python facebook-sdk upload multiple files

Tags: python, django, facebook-graph-api, upload, facebook-sdk-3.0

I'm trying to post to the Page feed with multiple images. I'm following [Doc's](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/photo-uploads#publishing-a-multi-photo-story) Facebook Graph API and [Doc's](https://github.com/mobolic/facebook-sdk/blob/master/docs/api.rst) facebook-sdk for python. Only the message is published, without the image.

```
token = "my_token"

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token=token, version="3.0")
photo_id = graph.put_photo(image=open('favicon.png', 'rb'), published=False)
print('PHOTO ID ', photo_id.get('id', ''))
post = graph.put_object(parent_object="page_id", connection_name="feed", message="Message with images upload!", attachments=[{'media_fbid': photo_id.get('id', '')}])
print('POST ID', post.get('id', ''))
```

Image and post IDs are returned without errors. However, the image is not published along with the message. I'm using *attachments* parameter, maybe it's another. Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

**I found the [answer](https://github.com/mobolic/facebook-sdk/issues/401#issuecomment-354303521):**

You should use *json.dumps* and *attached_media* as parameter:

```
import json

graph.put_object(parent_object="page_id", connection_name="feed", message="Message with multiple files!", attached_media=json.dumps([{'media_fbid': str(photo_id.get('id', ''))}]))
```